# Unwind multiple arrays from different structure in document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have these two types of structures in my collection:

```
{
    _id: "date1",
    users: [{"user": "123", ...}, {"user": "456", ...}]
}
```

and

```
{
    _id: "date2",
    points: [{"point": "1234", ...}, {"point": "5678", ...}]
}
```

I need to make an agregation, that returns me a list of these documents and only the specific point or user information and with skip and limit. Something like:

```
[
    {_id: "date1", user: {"user": "123", ...}},
    {_id: "date2", point: {"point": "1234", ...}},
]
```

I have used, I'm new in mongo, can you have me any recommendation?

```
collection.aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$users"},
{"$unwind": "$points"},
{"$match": {"$or": [
    {'users.user': an_user},
    {'points.point': a_point}]}},
{"$sort": {"_id": -1}},
{"$skip": 10},
{"$limit": 10}
])
```

Comment: For what purpose are you unwinding? Are you trying to filter the content in the arrays? The OR condtion does not really make your intentions that clear. Aside from the problem of a cartesian product, it's not sure what result you expect. So perhaps expand on your sample to demonstrate what the result should be.

Comment: I need a result that returns me a list in a range of `_id:date`, with the information of one specific user or one specific point depending if `point` or `user` key is in that document. No matter the result structure. Maybe unwind is not the solution, could be group. As I said, I'm new in mongo.

Comment: How many documents are there in the collection? Is there a requirement to fetch in one operation ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar the only requirement is to return one point, or one user information, from each document, in a range of dates. I gave two parameters in a Rest resource `url/<user>?point=<point>` I need to find information, by point or by user, according to the document structure.

Answer (score 0):

> with the information of one specific user or one specific point depending if point or user key is in that document

Given your provided document example you may be able to just utilise [db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), for example:

```
db.collection.find({"users.user": a_user}, {"users.$":1});
db.collection.find({"points.point": a_point}, {"points.$":1});
```

Depending on your use case, this may not be ideal because you're executing `find()` twice. 
This would return your a list of documents with their `_id`. The above query is equivalent to saying:

```
Find all documents in the collection 
where in array field users contain a user 'a_user' 
OR in array field points contain a point 'a_point'
```

See also [MongoDB Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

Having said the above, you should *really reconsider* your document schema. Depending on your use case, you may find difficulties in querying the data later on and may impact your query performance. Please review [MongoDB Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) to provide more information on how to design your schema.